# Проблемы с виджетом Twitter в sortable контейнере

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, twitter, javascript

Сегодня столкнулся с еще одним глюком. На сайте в правом сайдбаре находятся share боксы фейсбука и твиттера, они помешены в ul li и обрабатываются плагином sortable jquery-ui для того, чтобы пользователи могли их сортировать между собой (не задумывайтесь зачем это - так захотели клиенты). Суть проблемы в том что когда хочешь передвинуть бокс с твиттером, происходит какое-то событие(курсор мыши прилипает к метке и даже если отпустить левую кнопку мыши бокс следует за курсором), а после того как мы переставили этот блок происходит перезагрузка страницы, правда мы видим только белый экран. Может кто знает что это может быть за глюки. (Все на локальной машине)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно,что никто не ответил, но проблему решил сам. Просто когда сортебле переставляет блоки и браузер перерисовывает их на новых местах, твиттеровский скрипт отрабатывал снова, что приводило к багу. Я не стал копаться в скриптах, а просто вынес вызов скрипта виджета на другую хтмл страницу и подгружал ее через ифрейм, конечно решение не очень "красивое", зато все работает.